# Cannot setText after changing value from firestore

Tags: android, date, google-cloud-firestore, time

I am working on retrieve the values from firestore into android studio. I got every values except for my Date. I have tried to put the breakpoint and check the problem and I found out that I can get the values but cannot be set into TextView.
Below is my recyclerViewAdapter

```
 adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<History, BusViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BusViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull History model) {

           // holder.time.setText(model.getDate());
            holder.name.setText(String.valueOf(model.getFullName()));
            holder.medicine.setText(model.getMedicine());
            holder.illness.setText(model.getIllness());
            Long timestamp=model.getDate().getTime();

            String todisplaycurrenttimewithdate = getTimeDate(timestamp);

            //SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
            String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(todisplaycurrenttimewithdate));
            holder.time.setText(dateString);//The problem is in this line
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public BusViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(AdminHistoryActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.history_recyclerview, parent, false);
            return new BusViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And also this is my method to change the date into SimpleDateFormat

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timestamp){
    try{
        Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));
        SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        return sfd.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

The only data I can't get is the time. Can anyone help :(

Edit**
This is my firestore structure for History.
[Firestore Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tz8D.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated. Please help me to take a look. thank you so much!

Comment: Please also edit your question and add the content of your `History` class.